# Ubuntu MySQL: Job failed to start

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

My Google Cloud server HDD space run out. So I've added another mounted HDD where I copied contents of MySQL data (/var/lib/mysql/*). After updating my.cnf when I tried to restart MySQL it fails leaving the following error:

```
160110 14:10:40 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use$
160110 14:10:40 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
^G/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
160110 14:10:40 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
160110 14:10:40 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160110 14:10:40 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160110 14:10:40 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160110 14:10:40 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160110 14:10:40 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160110 14:10:40 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160110 14:10:40  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
160110 14:10:41 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use$
160110 14:10:41 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
^G/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
160110 14:10:41 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
160110 14:10:41 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160110 14:10:41 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160110 14:10:41 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160110 14:10:41 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160110 14:10:41 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160110 14:10:41 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160110 14:10:41  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
160110 14:10:42 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use$
160110 14:10:42 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
^G/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
160110 14:10:42 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
160110 14:10:42 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160110 14:10:42 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160110 14:10:42 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160110 14:10:41 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160110 14:10:41 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160110 14:10:41 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160110 14:10:41  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
160110 14:10:42 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use$
160110 14:10:42 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
^G/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
160110 14:10:42 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
160110 14:10:42 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160110 14:10:42 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160110 14:10:42 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160110 14:10:42 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160110 14:10:42 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160110 14:10:42 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160110 14:10:42  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

I've tried chmod 777 and chown mysql:mysql to the mounted folder (/var/www/html/DB/) but the result is same. After using chown, I can even see that the owner is now mysql. So why MySQL is failing to access the folder?

I've seen similar question here but most of the accepted answers are reinstalling MySQL. That's not a solution to me. It's simply bypassing the problem. Any better answer?

Comment: Did you do the other thing it's telling you to do (" Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.")?

Comment: check the permission and the owner of the subfolders. you can look in the original folders

Comment: @Pekka웃: I've tried that and here's the output: # mysql_upgrade
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

Comment: @BerndBuffen: I've set owner to mysql:mysql. Still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check that you have set all your config file where you have to change directory path in my.cnf

Also make sure you have change the profile for mysqld that mean you have to update AppArmor config file so it will get the new directory.

Check this link https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/entry/apparmor_and_mysql

I hope this will work!!